# What are the differences between p-adic Whittaker functions and archimedean Whittaker functions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

What are the differences between p-adic Whittaker functions and archimedean Whittaker functions? Are there some references about the differences? Thank you very much.